# Add to cart button not adding product in cart

Tags: magento

I have created a new1.phtml file in catalog/product with following content

```
<?php
        //getting new product collection

        $product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
        $filtered_prodduct=$product->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                                    ->setOrder("created_at","desc")
                                    ->addPriceData();
        echo "<ul>
                <li>";
                $i=0;
                $row=3;
        foreach($filtered_prodduct as $prod){ 
            $i++;
            if($i>$row*3){
                break;
            }
            ?>
        <div class="prod_box">
            <div class="center_prod_box">
                <div class="product_title">
                    <a href="<?php echo $prod->getProductUrl()?>">
                        <?php echo $prod->getName() ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product_img">
                    <a href="<?php echo $prod->getproductUrl()?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $prod->getImageUrl()?>" alt=""          border="0" height="100" width="100"> 

                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="prod_price">
                    <span class="reduce"><?php echo $prod->getSpecialPrice()?></span>
                    <span class="price"><?php echo $prod->getPrice()?></span><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="prod_details_tab">

                <?php if($prod->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl()?>checkout/cart/add? product=<?php echo $prod->getId(); ?>&qty=1" class="prod_buy">
                            <?php echo $this->__('Add') ?>
                        </a>

                    <?php else: ?>
                         <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span>
                 <?php echo   $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $prod->getProductUrl()?>" class="prod_details">
                    Details
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } 
      ?>
```

Every thing is ok ,but 'Add' button (means add to cart) is not working .It just opens checkout/cart.

i have added this phtml file in layout xml of home page. what is wrong in the code ?

Comment: No. It is   add?product=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(($prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this my using below code `,which generated add to cart url`.

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(($prod);
```

If product  `type  is configurable and  group or if product type is simple and it have customoption`   ,then it did not cart directly  without selecting any options

Answer (score 0):

The controller's action validates request therefore you should send formKey

`public function addAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
       ...
    {`